# Passing array in long running background shell script prior to multithreading

Tags: php, linux, multithreading, shell

In crontab, I have added a php script name, running this script from CLI SAPI mode, so no max_execution_time problem.

I can pass several parameters using spaces.

```
system('/path/of/your/script.php param1 param2 > scriptlog.txt &')
```

But I need to pass an array as parameter is shell script and breakdown the array.

for example,

```
system('/path/of/your/script.php array > scriptlog.txt &')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cast [`system`](http://php.net/system) in your app, you must [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) your parameters
Just pass arguments successively like

```
system('/path/of/your/script.php param[0] param[1] > scriptlog.txt &')
```

This would look like

```
system('/path/of/your/script.php '.implode(" ",$params).' > scriptlog.txt &')
```

If you're having quotes, you can take a look at [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg)

```
system('/path/of/your/script.php '.implode(" ",array_map("escapeshellarg",$params)).' > scriptlog.txt &')
```

Then in your `script.php`, catch parameters with

```
$args = $argv;
array_shift($args); //Because $args[0] is 'script.php'
```

If you're catching `> scriptlog.txt &` in your `script.php`, use this instead:

```
$args = $argv;
if (false !== ($pos = array_search(">",$args))) {
    $args = array_slice($args,1,$pos-1);
} else {
    array_shift($args);
}
```

Note that this works only if your array is non-associative.
You'll need to write another function to retrieve associative params

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass the array out directly. Ideally what you want to do is pass out each member of the array as an individual paramater, then read them back to work with in your script. You could also pass out the number of paramaters to read to the script. 
IE.

```
$out = sizeof($array);
foreach ($array as $arg){
    $out = $out . ' ' . $arg;
}
```

This should give your out object a list like "4 param1 param2 param3 param4"

Then you just need to read these variables in using the ARGV in your bash script.

Alternately you could also use a field delimited list, read it as one argument and then split each of the array elements out using a split on your field delimiter.